# can i use another delta instead of lasco #0267 don't get enough hot water

Tags: plumbing

I have a lasco delta #0267 scald guard cartridge can I replace it with something else don't get enough hot water no matter what I do.

Comment: Do other fixtures give you an ample supply of hot water?\

Comment: What kind of water heater do you have--standard tank or tankless?